# How to refresh a Hive table metadata while connecting it from Tableau using Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, tableau-api, cloudera, impala

A table created and managed in Hive is being used from Tableau using an Impala connection. How can I execute 
`invalidate metadata tablename` from Tableau so that the metadata is updated after doing some altering from Hive.

Comment: Minor capitalization so product/software names are clearer.

Comment: Interesting question. I think you have to do it at upstream applications when you are actually loading the data into the specific table. But would be cool to do it from downstream applications.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using “Initial SQL” property and put into it the invalidate 
statement? This should be triggered for each new connection.
Other BI tools have also the possibility of adding this kind of sql statement/commands as “hooks” just before or after the execution of the query used to retrieve the data.
Another possibility could be a “first executed” empty report with the invalidate statement as custom sql query..